# Why is there no https protocol in ffmpeg found?

Tags: https, ffmpeg, openssl, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord.py musicbot. It should play music from there:

```
channel = message.author.voice.channel
    if message.content.startswith("IT play"):
        voicechannel = await channel.connect()
        songname = message.content.split(" ")[2]
        vurl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn4nL99Vb5A"
        song = pafy.new(vurl)
        audio = song.getbestaudio()
        print(audio.url)
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio.url)
        voicechannel.play(source)
```

but once I run the bot, this message appears:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHzq7.png)

Both links are identical. If there is a need for more code for you to help me, I will give it to you. I tried to find a solution myself, and I think, the problem is, that https is not an ffmpeg input. But as there are solutions for Linux- users, I wondered if there are solutions for Windows too, but I didn't find one. Also, I wasn't able to locate a ./configure -file. I would be thankful if I receive a very detailed answer, as I'm quite new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS support is provided by external libraries, which have to be linked at compile-time.

Both providers for Windows binaries provide such builds: http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: thank you, your comment gave me the right hint. I had different versions of ffmpeg installed the same time, and I wasn't able to uninstall an older version that doesn't support https:. Anyways, thank you!